# Wireless driver installation

Tags: wifi, drivers, release-hera

I just got a new computer (HP Envy) and installed elementary OS.
As you may know, a lot of HP laptops come with Intel wireless drivers and they do not work on Linux right after the installation. And mine is not an exception. I do not see wireless option in the network setting. Right now, I am connected to internet by USB tethering using my phone.

My wireless driver is **Intel Wireless AC9560**. I have tried many different methods online but failed. Could anyone help me get my wifi working?

p.s. I also could not install elementary tweaks on my computer. While adding the PPA, it always returned

```
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release
404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

Comment: For the elementary tweaks issue, you have to use phillip.scott ppa:
`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks`. Use `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily` to remove the obsolete mpstark repository.

Comment: This was great, thank you, I was able to have wifi following your instructions.
However the web became very slow, I followed a suggestion of inactivating 802. 11n found at https://www.edivaldobrito.com.br/dicas-para-aumentar-a-velocidade-da-internet/
and I lost the wifi!
Now I can't recover it back, is there any way to reactivate 802. 11n again? This is what I made:
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1?" >> /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf Can I reverse this action?

Answer (score 2):

Found a bunch of issues related to your wifi adapter and Ubuntu 18.04, but these two seem promising:

[Ubuntu not recognizing wifi device](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2432901&p=13915811#post13915811)  describes how to install the latest intel wifi drivers:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

[WiFi Adapter Not Found: Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-not-found-ubuntu-18-04) suggest a kernel upgrade to 5.3:

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

Comment: I have used it on OS hera (5.1), it worked, but I get an unstable connection (much lower bandwidth than expected).