# Intel® Wireless-AC 9560

Tags: wifi

I have an MSI Modern 14 A10RB that has an Intel® 9560 wireless adapter. While Debian and Ubuntu are able to recognize it without installing any firmware, this does not happen with Elementary.

I tried to install the firmware according to Intel instructions (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html)

I downloaded and unzipped it in the / lib / firmware folder. But it still doesn't work. Could it be that I am failing something?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You have the wifi card **Intel Wireless AC9560**

So I think this question asked here will help you, you have a very good answer from  [Vlad Pop](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/users/9445/vlad-pop)

[Qestion](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/21683/19360)

[Vlad Pop answer](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/a/21685/19360)