# no wifi adapter found after install

Tags: wifi, intel

when i boot with usb, no problem, wifi works, one installed, no wifi adapter is found, it's an intel wifi device.
I don't understand how come it can work with live usb and no more once installed !!

Comment: I have just the same problem. Could you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

i found a workaround but updates could remove it, it's not very practical but it works.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing

sudo apt-get software-properties-common

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms

sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge

my wifi card is Intel Wireless AC-9560 - I came across this on another [post](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/wireless-driver-installation/21685#21685)