# No Wireless Connection On Elementary OS On Hera 5.1

Tags: release-hera, wifi

I am using the Hera 5.1 I tried to restart network manager and there was a pop up but when I open Network Settings there was only vpn and proxy???

Comment: What sudo update-initramfs -u shows? Any errors about the missing firmware?

Answer (score 0):

Please open terminal and enter command "lspci" and show result. If you need quality help you add information about your PC

Answer (score 0):

i'v same problem. Wifi: Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz.
Now connected via TP-Link TL-WN722N

**dmesg | grep iwl**

```
[    5.304699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    5.304954] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.525204] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x354
[    6.542555] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    6.542650] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.542657] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: -1634907666
[    6.542661] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0
[    6.542666] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5A54FDBE | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT          
[    6.542669] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4241D017 | trm_hw_status0
[    6.542672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB5C509ED | trm_hw_status1
[    6.542675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2C9D909C | branchlink2
[    6.542679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF567E43D | interruptlink1
[    6.542682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA1885322 | interruptlink2
[    6.542685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA002F521 | data1
[    6.542688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xEDB18492 | data2
[    6.542691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9C9FFFC5 | data3
[    6.542694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x1F001658 | beacon time
[    6.542697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4BEB0398 | tsf low
[    6.542700] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x06BAEC53 | tsf hi
[    6.542703] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3AC98CD8 | time gp1
[    6.542706] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2F82CD4A | time gp2
[    6.542710] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0885690C | uCode revision type
[    6.542713] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5D16B806 | uCode version major
[    6.542716] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5D0A9B7A | uCode version minor
[    6.542719] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8C95003E | hw version
[    6.542722] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x787D3896 | board version
[    6.542725] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE390CFF0 | hcmd
[    6.542728] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x54598986 | isr0
[    6.542731] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2FAC8FDE | isr1
[    6.542734] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5AAB7205 | isr2
[    6.542737] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8961E389 | isr3
[    6.542740] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xD3E37B0A | isr4
[    6.542743] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xB6D5D8B7 | last cmd Id
[    6.542746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x77A6BA5A | wait_event
[    6.542749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x93A044E8 | l2p_control
[    6.542752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA2AD7B94 | l2p_duration
[    6.542755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2EEC3E93 | l2p_mhvalid
[    6.542758] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x144DF80B | l2p_addr_match
[    6.542761] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBC5583AD | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    6.542764] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC07CF1F0 | timestamp
[    6.542767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC9FDD67D | flow_handler
[    6.542806] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    6.542810] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    6.542813] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x201013F1 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    6.542817] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    6.542820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC008CF5C | umac branchlink2
[    6.542823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink1
[    6.542826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    6.542829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | umac data1
[    6.542832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | umac data2
[    6.542835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | umac data3
[    6.542838] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    6.542841] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    6.542844] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00005CA7 | frame pointer
[    6.542847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0887F58 | stack pointer
[    6.542850] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[    6.542853] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    6.542872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    6.542892] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    6.542897] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x80260000 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    6.542917] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020006 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    6.542939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A384 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    6.542960] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCC164E51 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    6.542981] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    6.542985] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    6.543005] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    6.543010] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000302 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.543032] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01300202 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    6.543054] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000485B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    6.543105] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    6.543141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5c17, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    6.543145] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    6.543152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    6.554600] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9b41 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 02f0
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e8
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02e9
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02e0
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 02d3
00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02c5
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 02a8
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02ab
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 02a4
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1d13 (rev a1)
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5006
```

Comment: What sudo update-initramfs -u shows? Any errors about the missing firmware?

Comment: Thanks great! This help me: https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/wireless-driver-installation/21685#21685

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can help you

Try restarting the wingpanel by `killall wingpanel`

If that doesn't work, try checking if you have `indicator-applet` & `indicator-application` installed or not.

If you already have them installed, try reinstalling `libappindicator` and then logout and log back in.

Use the following command to reinstall `libappindicator`

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libappindicator3-1 libappindicator1
```

If the above solutions doesn't work. Try reinstalling the network manager

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager network-manager-gnome
```